# How to fix 'Param _version does not exist' in cakephp 3 while saving data using elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, cakephp-3.7

I want to use elasticsearch  with cakephp 3 , there is an article related to this in cakephp cookbook [Click Here](https://book.cakephp.org/elasticsearch/2.x/en/). 
But while saving a record through cakephp 3, i am getting "Param _version does not exist" error from "ruflin\elastica\lib\Elastica\AbstractUpdateAction.php" this php file.

Comment: It might be helpful to show what code you're running that's generating this error. I'd assume you're likely updating an existing record, as the Document class is hard coded to return version 1 on new entities. Likely whatever query you're running to pull the record in the first place isn't returning a _version in its results, there's a few potential causes for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it,, by restarting the elasticsearch server, as i think the server got closed and due to which this error was coming.